# POST Query length limit on tomcat

Tags: ajax, jsp, tomcat, post

I am trying to send a very long POST request as an AJAX call in my application.  Up until the query length exceeds ~7585 characters (incl. page name) the request goes through fine.  However, there is a definite limit going on as adding a single character will make the request fail.

I have ensured that the tomcat server.xml config does not specify maxPostSize, and the documentation says it defaults to 2MB, which is way more room than I am using.

Am I missing something here?  I am suspicious that this is a limitation being imposed by the web browser (Firefox 3.6.18).

If this is just an unfortunate truth, how do people get around this?  By batching the data into smaller chunks manually?  It seems like this would be a common problem for people.  Thanks!

Comment: Just an update, I never found a solution to this problem, but ended up dealing with it by sending smaller POST messages WHILE the user was performing actions on the page, and this has fared well enough.