# ajax post, firefox and IE wont work

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm making an jquery ajax post to a php script.  this works in Chrome 19 and Safari 5.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    async:true,
    url: '/site/phpscript.php',
    data: {
            xyArray: xyArray,
            xmlDataString:xmlDataString,
            id:id
        },
    success: function(results){ alert('success'); },
    error: function()
    {
                alert('error');
    }
});
```

When I test this, this will work in chrome and safari.  but not in IE and firefox.
but.. if the size of the xmlDataString is small, it will work.

is there a size limitation for firefox when posting using jQuery ajax?

Comment: did you clear browser cache and try ?

Comment: It should work, press SHIFT+F5 in chrome or CTRL +F5 in firefox to clear cache for that page

Comment: Yes I tried that too, but i dont think its related to that.  perhaps its somethign to do with the size of the data being sent.

Comment: What is `xyArray` and `xmlDataString`. Also what means `won't work`? Do you mean the post executes, no script error shows up in firebug or post does not execute and error/or no error shows up in firebug?

Comment: wont work meaning im not able to get a response for the ajax call in IE and Firefox.  but i will get a response in chrome and safari.

Comment: oh another thign is, if the size of the post is small it will work around 150kb

Comment: xyArray is an array that contains x y coordinates, and xmlDataString is a string that which has xmlFormat

Comment: xmlDataString would look like this
<points><name>somename </name> <xy x="100" y="100"> </xy> ....many of these points ... </points>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Yes, Firefox has a limit of 4096 characters.

Some workaround in here:
http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?8208-Firefox-Ajax-limit-of-4096

EDIT: from that article:

I created a JS function to handle the "result" from the web service ajax call...which works in both FF and IE...

just call that instead...

```
var strResult=Ext.DomQuery.selectValue("string", result, "");
function getWebSvcString(result)

{

var strResult="";

var stringElement = result.getElementsByTagName("string")[0];

if (stringElement.text!=null &amp;&amp; stringElement!=undefined){

strResult=stringElement.text;

// alert("IE: "+strResult.length);

}


else if (stringElement.textContent!=null &amp;&amp; stringElement.textContent!=undefined)

{

strResult=stringElement.textContent;

// alert("FF: "+strResult.length);


}

return strResult;

}
```

Also, I would leave the Post out, as it is the default. It will just make your code cleaner. Also, I would add an error message to the response of the error event in your Ajax call. That might give a clue too.

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    url: '/site/phpscript.php',
    data: {
            xyArray: xyArray,
            xmlDataString:xmlDataString,
            id:id
        },
    success: function(results){ alert('success'); },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);

    }
});
```

In my experience, when browsers have trouble with Ajax calls it is because the data is malformed. Can you run the post and response through a validator? Perhaps there is a character missing, an extra comma somewhere, or a closing tag missing.

Comment: yes I tried the firefox debugger.  the net tab shows that post is aborted.  after about 20 seconds.

Comment: Looks like there is a limit in FF of 4096 characters.

Comment: i'm sure this is a common problem, has to be a fix for this.

Comment: Yes, it is in that link I posted above. I have now edited my response with a quote from that link.

Comment: yes i went throught that.  i'm not understanding how this would work.  is this something for the response, because i dont get any reponse.  i cant get the XHR to initialize when i have a large data.

Comment: It seems as though there is no solution since it is a restriction of the browser. Everyone says to find a way to break your posts into smaller calls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126254/post-query-length-limit-on-tomcat

Comment: You might also consider not using JQ. Here is a solution that changes the Get URL of the Post method: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?520812-textarea-size-Limit-in-AJAX&s=bcb0a92712f6051b82746d1a93dc1030&p=3659127&viewfull=1#post3659127

Comment: i'll mark this usefull, although i havnt resolved it, but its still useful.